# Change First Occurence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table that follows this format:

| Index | Another header | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| index1 | a | True |
|  | a | True |
|  | a | True |
|  | b | True |
| index2 | c | True |
| index2 | c | True |
| index2 | c | True |

The list is ordered by date (least recent to most recent). For each index, I want the most recent value in 'Another header' to remain True while changing the rest to False. And if the value only occurs once, it will become False. It should look something like this:

| Index | Another header | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| index1 | a | False |
|  | a | False |
|  | a | True |
|  | b | False |
| index2 | c | False |
|  | c | False |
|  | c | True |

Does anyone know how I can do this? All help is appreciated!

Comment: How do you say that its the most recent value? is there a datetime column, please post full minimal data

Comment: I can't post the data but it is sorted by datetime

Comment: then synthesize the data and post along with the datetime, we need to see some data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Value is already set to True, use boolean indexing:

```
g = df.groupby(['Index', 'Another header'])

# 0 = first of each group
m1 = g.cumcount().eq(0)
# 0 = last of each group
m2 = g.cumcount(False).ne(0)

df.loc[(m1|m2), 'Value'] = False
```

If the value is not yet set:

```
df['Value'] = ~(m1|m2)
```

output:

```
    Index Another header  Value
0  index1              a  False
1  index1              a  False
2  index1              a   True
3  index1              b  False
4  index2              c  False
5  index2              c  False
6  index2              c   True
```

intermediates:

```
    Index Another header  Value  cumcount     m1  cumcount2     m2  m1|m2
0  index1              a  False         0   True          2   True   True
1  index1              a  False         1  False          1   True   True
2  index1              a   True         2  False          0  False  False
3  index1              b  False         0   True          0  False   True
4  index2              c  False         0   True          2   True   True
5  index2              c  False         1  False          1   True   True
6  index2              c   True         2  False          0  False  False
```

Comment: Thank you! Just to better understand the code, would you mind explaining what cumcount does?

Comment: I provided the intermediates for clarity